# How to download all images as a zip file in Angular

Tags: angular, jszip, filesaver.js

I want to download all the images as a zip file, so I am using `jszip`, `jszip-utils`, `file-saver` libraries.

This is what I'm doing:

```
const zip = new JSZip();
let count = 0;
const zipFilename = "document-preview.zip";

this.imgUrls.forEach((url) => {
// loading a file and add it in a zip file
JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, (err, data) => {
   if (err) {
      throw err; // or handle the error
   }
   count = count + 1;
   const filename = `Preview-${count}.jpeg`;
   zip.file(filename, data, { binary: true });
   if (count === this.imgUrls.length) {
     zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }).then(function (content) {
       saveAs(content, zipFilename);
     });
  }
});
```

The problem is that the given URL serves images only once (configured on the server), so when images are rendered on the screen using `img`, the URLs that are hit by above code return an empty image. So the downloaded zip shows empty images.

Now how can download all the images from loaded DOM as zip?

Comment: I had a similar issue, when I tried to create base64 png images from canvas and download them (about 18k-20k pictures). The trick was I waited the next frame so browser could render them properly. If you group your render calls into window.requestAnimationFrame(async () => { myAsyncCalls.. }); and await them (use async), then you should get the wished behaviour.